# Android: Parsing XML file which contain Html Entities, Html Characters and URL Addresses?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, url-encoding, html-encode, domparser

I'm trying to parse XML file (RSS Feed), but I have a problem that the xml file contains HTML Entities Character, and it doesn't appear when I convert it to string and I don't know how to encode it:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {} 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} 
    catch (IOException e) {}
```

For example: This is the text I want to get in my java code

```
<description>
     Amman Post: Shath'a Hasson pointed on the reason about &nbsp .... .... ...
</description>
```

But in the string I lose all the text after this character &nbsp

And when i tried to parse a URL Address:

http://www.ammanpost.net/index.php?page=article&id=25981

what I get in the string is this:

http://www.ammanpost.net/index.php?page=article

I lose every thing after '&' character.

Can you help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Parser doesn't support to parse special characters...

Comment: @SudiptaforAndroid what's the solution ?? can't I parse URL at least ?

Comment: ask your server developer to remove special characters...

Comment: @SudiptaforAndroid What about URL ADDRESS T__T server developer can't control that !

Comment: give me the url address which is binded in xml code

Comment: @SudiptaforAndroid  

This is the RSS Feed
http://ammanpost.net/rss.php?type=main

http://www.ammanpost.net/index.php?page=article&id=26091 ,,, 

http://www.ammanpost.net/index.php?page=article&id=25996 ,,, 

http://www.ammanpost.net/index.php?page=article&id=25998 ,,, 

these are links to the news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem with my app too, I managed to fix it with the [Html class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)
like so :

```
Html.fromHtml(string);
```

for the URL problem, check out the [URLDecoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

Comment: HTML.fromHtml(string);
this return Spanned object and am using DOM parser so I can parse it 
the problem in parser itself
,                                                                      
String x = parser.getValue(e, "description");

when I print xml file everything is ok ,

but when i get a node value it gets wrong value ??